# Share wordpress site between two different user tables

Tags: php, iphone, wordpress

I have a wordpress site, and a iphone app for the same.Both have a common database with different user tables.

1> mysite.com >> wp_user

2> iPhone app >> app_user

what i want that, i want to make able app user login to the WordPress site. means

1> site user can only able to login into site

2> app user can login into site + iPhone app

how can i make app user able to login into site.

i have tried by debugging WP-login script, but can't find correct way

i need help from you guys.

thanks.

Comment: Can't you just copy the record from app_user to wp_user?

Comment: @MythThrazz it's not appropriate , cause i have to do it same for all time for each app_user added

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The required functionality looks a bit tricky, there might be more methods possible but the one I will recommend is:

- Create a custom login form in wordpress site
- Retrieve the username and password and first check if they exists on your site or not. If they do exist then simply login (these are site users) `wp_signon` method can be used here.
- If they are not wordpress users then check if they are mobile app user by using `MySQL` and looking into the mobile app table, if they do exists then retrieve their information and register them into `WordPress` site `wp_create_user` can be used for it, you can add custom meta data so that you know these are app users. After registering, create login session using `wp_signon`.

I will recommend you to build a plugin for this task in wordpress.

Happy coding !

Answer (score 2):

You could use extend the WordPress XML-RPC API to authenticate your iphone user to wordpress. Detailed explanation and basic working code can be found at *Extending the WordPress XML-RPC API* (http://www.skyverge.com/blog/extending-the-wordpress-xml-rpc-api/).

Comment: +1 - this is the way the official WP android app works!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a custom login plugin to accomplish this.

You can use [wp-rename](http://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-wp-login/) login plugin as a start up point for this.

In this plugin the WP credentials validation part is handled In the file rwl-login.php at line 449.

Similarly you have to add code to validate the mobile credentials as well in this switch case.
If you have built your code adhering to WP mobile app standards you can just include login validation file as it is done for WP regular validation in line 450

if not do your own validation and redirect properly in that case You may also have your native app register the handler of that custom url so that it can catch and handle the redirect appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 user groups namely:

1. Site User
2. App User

When the user tries to login, check the user group it belongs to and accordingly provide the access or display an error message.

For making changes to the login system user the filter hook "**authenticate**" or even better use [wp_authenticate](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_authenticate)

Comment: thanks for the rply.but you didn't get my question properly? i have asked about how to access WP from webservise/mobile app(iphone) which is in same directory of wordpress and have same DB ?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out loud - first a confirmation of the core problem:

You need a user to be able to log into the iOS app and grant access to the WP site.

Current consideration : On the iOS app and wordpress create a hash of user ID + password + salt (or something of that ilk).  Use that hash, sent via the iOS app to WP, to confirm a user.

Yes, there are security issues regarding this info going over the air, just as your username and PW would go over the air.

With a matching hash (use a look up table in WP, super easy), there are methods in WP to force a user log-in (done that, could dig out code helpers from my archives).

Issue : Need to hook PW change to hash generation / update. There are user change hooks in WP, very solvable.

Good to know : Almost every aspect of user management, including permission and groups, are available via the WP API/framework. It is possible (although not easy) to put a change PW on the iOS app that will update WP and much more.

Hope I helped you along, the messages are a little confusing.